# Screen doesn‘t Turn on after powering my laptop on

Tags: boot, grub2, 22.04

Hello everyone I’ve recently installed ubuntu 22.04 on my Lenovo l14 g4 thinkpad and everything worked fine.

Now when I turn on my laptop the screen isn’t reacting at all and I only get black screen. I’ve tried turning it on and off but it’s still didn’t react.

I tried entering grub mode with `esc`, `shift`, `F1` and `F12` but but couldn’t enter it. Can someone help me with this issue?

Comment: Are you even seeing like the logo when you power it on?  Sounds like it is not an OS issue, but an issue with the device itself.   Try doing a power reset of it by powering it off, then unplugging the power from it and holding down the power button for 30 seconds.  Then plug it back in and power it back on.

Comment: I’ve reseted my laptop by clicking the reset button on the bottom of my laptop. I hope this can help someone.

Comment: You are more than welcome to write your own answer here on what helped you solve the problem.  Q&A here is highly encouraged.  Then after a certain amount of time you can select your answer as being correct.

Comment: The issues is happening when my laptop is entering the suspend mode, after i updated my laptop the issue can be resolved by powering off the laptop from the power button. Does anybody know why this happens in suspend mode and how this can be avoided?